# Throwing exception on mongoose callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm developing a Node.js + Express. My database is Mongo, and I'm using Mongoose to connect to this database.

I'm trying to throw an exception in a Mongoose query callback this way:

```
game.save(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    throw new app.exception.EntitySaveFailed();
  }          
});
```

but when I do it, Node server crashes and shows this stacktrace:

```
[object Object]
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/server/routes/api/game.js:219:17)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:162:8)
    at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Promise.emit (/home/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:79:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (/home/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:92:20)
    at Promise.resolve (/home/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:108:15)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:162:8)
    at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Promise.emit (/home/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:79:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (/home/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:92:20)
Forever detected script exited with code: 8
Forever restarting script for 9389 time
Listening on port 3000...
```

When I throw an exception outside a mongoose callback function, all works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you throw an exception in a node.js callback it goes to the code that actually invoked the callback, not the lexical scope of your code.  In this case, that means the `Promise` library receives the exception and crashes your program.  This is why errors are typically reported via the first callback parameter rather than exceptions.

Comment: I tried to use Exceptions instead of passing info via parameters looking for cuteness/readability code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add "next" to the params of the function, so when you need to throw an exception you can do something like this:

```
function saveGame(req, res, next) {
  game.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return next(new app.exception.EntitySaveFailed());
    }          
  });
}
```